# ¿Por que visual basic.net no puede hacer una conexión con una base de datos con campos calculados hecho en access?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Tengo una base de datos hecho en access de ventas de productos pero tengo un campo calculado pero en visual basic.net no me deja hacer la conexión con esa base de datos, no sé porque se deberá esto y si tiene alguna solución?

Comment: Muestranos el código que utilizas para realizar la conexión, si eso no podremos ayudarte

Comment: El campo calculado ¿Está en una tabla o una query?

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes Es una tabla